# integrable random variables $X,Y$ such that $E(X|Y)=X$ a.s. and $E(Y|X)=Y$ a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, expected-value

Let $X,Y$ are random variables such that $E(|X|)+E(|Y|)<\infty$, and the random variable $E(X|Y)=X$ a.s. and $E(Y|X)=Y$ a.s .

Then is it true that $X=Y$ a.s. ?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @norfair: I'm not sure ... the converse is definitely true ... I also know that $X,Y$ integrable and $E(X|Y)=Y$ and $E(Y|X)=X$ a.s. implies $X=Y$ a.s. but I haven't been able to figure out the one I ask ...

Comment: @norfair: do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Y=X^{3}$ then  the two equations are satisfied but $X =Y$ may not hold.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y=2X$ for any nondegenerate and integrable RV $X.$